# PHP soap issues

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

**Drupal 7-soap**

This is the error which iam getting in error log and when iam trying to print the
**test.wsdl** file

```
SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document in SoapClient->__call()
```

[image]

I have no clue what is the error

My project environment

> PHP : 5.4.11
>
> MySQL : 5.5.27   Apache : 2.2.3
>
> OS : CentOS 5.8

code information

```
function ai_server() {
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
  $server = new SoapServer(file_create_url(variable_get('app_integration_wsdl')), array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));
  $server->addFunction('getData');
  $server->addFunction('getId');
  $server->addFunction('getInfo');
  $server->addFunction('getrightsInfo');
  $server->addFunction('updateInfo');
  $server->addFunction('resetAppHistory');
  //$server->addFunction('resetAppId');

  $server->handle();
}
```

**soap client**

```
function ai_sync_test() {
  ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
//
// ---------------------------------------------------------------- basic tests
//

  // is settings file accessible
  $settings_file = variable_get('app_integration_settings');
  require_once($settings_file);
  $settings_output = is_readable($settings_file) ? 'Ok! Settings file is readable.' : 'Error! Not readable or accessible.';

  // is wsdl file accessible
  $wsdl_file = variable_get('app_integration_wsdl');
  $wsdl_output = is_readable($wsdl_file) ? 'Ok! WSDL file is readable. ' . l('Open it. ', $wsdl_file, array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'))) : 'Error! Not readable or accessible. ';
  $wsdl_output .= 'You need to define domain name in it into this sections (at the bottom of app_integration.wsdl file): ';
  $wsdl_output .= htmlentities('<soap:address location="http://YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE/app_integration/server"/>');

  // methods, which integration service is provide
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl_file, array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));

  $methods = $client->__getFunctions();
  $methods_output = '';
  foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $methods_output .= '<li>' . $method . '</li>';
  }
```

Comment: please provide more details. code that you run at least

Comment: @DenisAlimov there you go

Comment: Try to invoke the client with the trace option set to TRUE and check the actual XML send/received via the __getLastRequest() and __getLastResponse() methods.

Comment: @bxN5 its empty

Comment: it's SOAP server. and you call SoapClient somewhere. provide that code

Comment: @DenisAlimov soap client code is posted above

Comment: @DenisAlimov did you get a chance to see the code above?

Comment: @bxN5 soap client code is above

Comment: @MadhuNair, please try using    NuSOAP - SOAP Toolkit for PHP from here, https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possible reasons -

1. You are echoing something in the code, or whitespace characters are getting printed or trailing new line character.
2. The server SOAP file in php has encode utf8 with BOM, causing apache send back the BOM mark (3 bytes) before the xml response. Encode your php file soap server with utf8 WITH OUT BOM mark.

```html
function strip_bom($str){
    return preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $str );
}
```